# How to compute aggregations on a range of thresholds?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.1,0],[0.2,1],[0.3,1],[0.4,0]], columns = ['score', 'correct_pred'])

     score  correct_pred
0    0.1             0
1    0.2             1
2    0.3             1
3    0.4             0
```

And I would like for each row to compute the proportion of lines with score below and the proportion of correct_pred with score equal or above.

That is, for the second row for instance, 25% of the rows have a score below 0.2 and 66% of rows equal or above 0.2 have a correct pred. The output would then look like:

```
threshold    percentage_filtered    percentage_correct_pred
0.1          0                      0.5
0.2          0.25                   0.66
0.3          0.5                    0.5
0.4          0.75                   0
```

So far I do it using this piece of code:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['threshold', 'percentage_filtered', 'percentage_correct_pred'])
for threshold in df.score:
    threshold_mask = df.score < threshold
    out.loc[len(out)] = [threshold, 
                         np.mean(threshold_mask), 
                         df[~threshold_mask].correct_pred.mean()]
```

Which works, but it is terribly slow on a real-size dataframe. So I need a faster version, I suspect there is a more vectorized method, maybe using `numpy.cumsum` or something?

Comment: Can there be repeated `score` values?

Comment: Indeed, in that case I don't want to repeat the computation. In my real piece of code I use for the loop: `list(set(df.score))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that `score` may have repeated values, but if it does not it would also work (although it could be simpler). This is a way to get that result:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[0.1, 0], [0.2, 1], [0.3, 1], [0.4, 0]],
                  columns=['score', 'correct_pred'])
# Group by scores and count occurrences and number of correct predictions
df2 = (df.sort_values('score')
       .groupby('score')['correct_pred']
       .agg(['count', 'sum'])
       .reset_index())
# Percentage of values below each threshold
perc_filtered = df2['count'].shift(1).fillna(0).cumsum() / df2['count'].sum()
# Percentage of values above each threshold with correct prediction
perc_correct_pred = df2['sum'][::-1].cumsum()[::-1] / df2['count'][::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
# Assemble result
result = pd.concat([df2['score'], perc_filtered, perc_correct_pred], axis=1)
result.columns = ['threshold', 'percentage_filtered', 'percentage_correct_pred']
print(result)
#    threshold  percentage_filtered  percentage_correct_pred
# 0        0.1                 0.00                 0.500000
# 1        0.2                 0.25                 0.666667
# 2        0.3                 0.50                 0.500000
# 3        0.4                 0.75                 0.000000
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(123)

df = pd.DataFrame({'score': np.arange(0, 1, 0.0005),
                   'correct_pred':np.random.choice([1,0], size=2000)
                   })

print (df)
       score  correct_pred
0     0.0000             1
1     0.0005             0
2     0.0010             1
3     0.0015             1
4     0.0020             1
     ...           ...
1995  0.9975             0
1996  0.9980             0
1997  0.9985             1
1998  0.9990             1
1999  0.9995             1

[2000 rows x 2 columns]

In [208]: %timeit do_it_jdehesa()
9.57 ms ± 317 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [209]: %timeit do_it()
5.83 s ± 181 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [210]: %timeit do_it1()
3.21 s ± 203 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [211]: %timeit do_it2()
92.5 ms ± 1.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Can I change your solution with timings?

Comment: @jezrael Of course, thank you (if you're posting your own solution later, note that these are your timings, so it's clear that they are comparable with the ones you post).

Comment: As pointed out by jezrael, this solution is faster on larger dataframes. I tested out on a sample of my real dataset (>50k rows), and it's a thousand times faster than the optimized loop in Nikolas Rieble's answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lets improve the runtime by a factor of 10.

For reference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.1,0],[0.2,1],[0.3,1],[0.4,0]], columns = ['score', 'correct_pred'])

def do_it():
    out = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['threshold', 'percentage_filtered', 'percentage_correct_pred'])
    for threshold in df.score:
        threshold_mask = df.score < threshold
        out.loc[len(out)] = [threshold, 
                             np.mean(threshold_mask), 
                             df[~threshold_mask].correct_pred.mean()]

%timeit do_it()
```

**13 ms ± 607 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)**

Firstly, we take all call of pandas methods out of the loop such as:

```
def do_it1():

    score_values = df.score.values
    score_list = list(set(score_values))

    correct_pred = df.correct_pred.values

    out = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['threshold', 'percentage_filtered', 'percentage_correct_pred'])

    for threshold in score_list:
        mask = score_values < threshold
        out.loc[len(out)] = [threshold, 
                             np.mean(mask), 
                             np.mean(correct_pred[~mask])]

%timeit do_it1()
```

**9.67 ms ± 331 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)**

Then we also create the dataframe only after getting the results

```
def do_it2():

    score_values = df.score.values
    score_list = list(set(score_values))

    correct_pred = df.correct_pred.values

    result = []
    for threshold in score_list:
        mask = score_values < threshold
        result.append((threshold,np.mean(mask),np.mean(correct_pred[~mask])))

    out = pd.DataFrame(result, columns = ['threshold', 'percentage_filtered', 'percentage_correct_pred'])

%timeit do_it2()
```

**960 µs ± 16.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)**

EDIT:
To take jdehesas answer into account:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.1, 0], [0.2, 1], [0.3, 1], [0.4, 0]],
                  columns=['score', 'correct_pred'])
def do_it_jdehesa():
    # Group by scores and count occurrences and number of correct predictions
    df2 = (df.sort_values('score')
           .groupby('score')['correct_pred']
           .agg(['count', 'sum'])
           .reset_index())
    # Percentage of values below each threshold
    perc_filtered = df2['count'].shift(1).fillna(0).cumsum() / df2['count'].sum()
    # Percentage of values above each threshold with correct prediction
    perc_correct_pred = df2['sum'][::-1].cumsum()[::-1] / df2['count'][::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
    # Assemble result
    result = pd.concat([df2['score'], perc_filtered, perc_correct_pred], axis=1)
    result.columns = ['threshold', 'percentage_filtered', 'percentage_correct_pred']

%timeit do_it_jdehesa()
```

**13.5 ms ± 997 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)**

EDIT2: Just optimizing the cuntion a little more - yet no where near as fast as jdehesas answer

```
def do_it5():

    dfarray = df.values
    n = dfarray.size
    score_values = dfarray[:,0]
    score_list = np.unique(score_values)    
    correct_pred = dfarray[:,1]

    result = []
    for threshold in score_list:
        mask = score_values<threshold
        result.append((threshold, np.count_nonzero(mask)/n, np.count_nonzero(correct_pred[~mask])/n))

    result =  pd.DataFrame(result, columns = ['threshold', 'percentage_filtered', 'percentage_correct_pred'])
```

Comment: Never test small data, because get wrong output - your slow solution seems fast.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I had no idea that repeated calls to pandas could dampen the performances so badly. As pointed at by jezrael, jdehesa's solution is faster on larger dataframes, but it was helpful as well!

Comment: Good point, thanks for mentioning. I will not delete this answer in order to let others profit from my mistake as well.